# Retaining Google API authorization in desktop app

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

When connecting to the google services from a desktop app user is required to enter access code provided to him to generate accessToken.
I can't quite understand how to properly save it and restore into GoogleCredential so user wouldn't have to authorize my app on every launch.

Can somebody provide me with a code snippet of this process or a more detailed instruction than the one Google provides?

Answer (score 0):

- First you have to register your project into the Google Developer console. From the console your will get some credentials like: cliend id, client secrets.
- Now when you want to authorize your application u need to get an access token. But before u have to get an "authorization token". For this u need to use an url like this

  ```
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
  redirect_uri=yourredirectpage&
  response_type=code&
  client_id=1070885696038-32m83k9ties5m7qsi4g6v8dfo28f2r9g.apps.googleusercontent.com&
  scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar&
  approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline
  ```

The response of this request contains the authorization token. Now you can exchange the authorization token for the access token with another request:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?
code=4/oIdtdqPBW67CTSpijkm_fbwCqMjF_WJPiSmvsq8zScA.Ilw2ePhp3fQeoiIBeO6P2m_Usz4vlgI&
client_id=1070885696038-32m83k9ties5m7qsi4g6v8dfo28f2r9g.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={your_client_secret}&
redirect_uri=yourredirectpage&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Where "code" is the authorization_token.

For more details check this: [Google Api OAuth](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent)

Comment: Sorry, i might not phrased it correctly. I can authorize and do everything just fine. But i can't figure out how to retain authorization next time application is launched. If i just use the same auth token server says that (naturally) token has expired.

Comment: If you check the page i've linked u can read how to refresh your token.